# Irreducible Polynomial-Am I doing this wrong?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Ok,this problem might appear a bit trivial but I have some doubts..If it's not a burden take a look and comment!

Let $F$ be a finite field of characteristic equal to $p$ and $ƒ(x)=x^p-α$ $∊F[x]$.Show that $ƒ(x)$ either has one root of multiplicity equal to $p$ or that $ƒ(x)$ is irreducible over $F$.

My answer:

Let $x₁$ and $x₂$ be two different roots of $ƒ(x)$.
Then it follows: $x₁^p-α=x₂^p-α=0$ ⇒$x₁^p-x₂^p=0$ 
But since the characteristic of the field is $p$,it derives from Euler's theorem that in general: $(b-c)^p=b^p-c^p$ for any $b,c∊F$

Thus:$(x₁-x₂)^p=0⇒x₁=x₂$.
So $ƒ(x)$ can have no distinct roots.
If $α$ is a root,then indeed $(x-α)^p=0$ and $α$ is a root of multiplicity equal to $p$.
Since no other factorization of $ƒ(x)$ exists-that is one that does not include the $(x-α)$ factor,it follows that if $α$ is not a root,then $ƒ(x)$ is irreducible.

Comment: What are your doubts? Anyway, you have shown that if there is a root, it is a p-repeated root. However maybe the polynomial factors into non linear factors? You also have to show that it does not.

Comment: My doubts center on the conditions by which $α$ is a root as well as the polynomial having a different factorization.

Comment: Are you sure that you used the correct statement of a problem ? In a *finite* field of cardinality $p^e$, the polynomial $x^p-a$ *always* factors as $(x-a^{p^{e-1}})^p$ (since $a^{p^e} = a$). The second branch of the alternative, $x^p - a$ irreducible, may only ever happen in an infinite field (example: $k = \mathbb F_p(t)$ and the polynomial $x^p-t$).

Comment: The statement is correct Circonflexe.What you suggest is what perplexes me as well.I think I see the solution now though..              Since there will always be a factorization of the form $(x-α)^p$,it follows that either $α=0$ in $F$,that is $gcd(α,p)=p$ and $f(x)=x^p$,thus it is irreducible,
or $α ≠0$ in $F$ and $f(x)=(x-α)^p$ and $α$ is a root of multiplicity equal to p.                                                                                                           If this is correct let me know and I 'll post it as an answer(Sorry,I am really new here so..)